# Next.js dynamic route right after index

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

Typically in Next.js you can achieve dynamic routes with file structures such as:

*pages/products/[id].js* which would lead to [www.website.com/products/productId2323](http://www.website.com/products/productId2323)

I am trying to achieve a "workspace" identifier in my route so that when a user logs in, their relevant workspace is retrieved from an API and then they can be routed to a route belonging to that workspace, in example:

[www.website.com/WorkSpaceName/](http://www.website.com/WorkSpaceName/)

Is it possible to do this without having to have some in-between slug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group all "namespaced" routes like this:

```
[18:10:47] /tmp/my-app ● $ tree -n 2 pages/
2 [error opening dir]
pages/
├── _app.js
├── index.js
├── posts
│   ├── [id].js
│   └── index.js
└── [workspace]
    ├── dashboard.js
    └── index.js

2 directories, 6 files
```

In which case requesting:

- `/something/dashboard` will be routed to the `pages/[workspace]/dashboard.js`
- `/something` will be routed to `pages/[workspace]/index.js`
- `/posts` will be routed to `pages/posts/index.js` (because non-dynamic routes take precedence over dynamic ones)
- `/posts/something` will be routed to `pages/posts/[id].js`

Within the `pages/[workspace]/dashboard.js` and `pages/[workspace]/index.js` files, probing the router like this:

```
[18:10:50] /tmp/my-app ● $ cat pages/\[workspace\]/dashboard.js 
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Dashboard = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const workspace = router.query.workspace

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Dashboard: {workspace}</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Should yield the expected value assigned to the `workspace` variable (so visiting `/something/dashboard` should render `Dashboard: something`).